# Semantic UI not loading in Vue project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, semantic-ui

I'm building my first website with Vue.JS as data framework and Semantic UI as CSS framework. I'm using a NodeJS package to create my Javascript files. Within my NodeJS package, I installed Semantic UI CSS with the

```sh
npm install semantic-ui-css
```

command, which is working. I see the directory in my node_modules directory, so I assume it is installed correctly. I also see semantic-ui-css as a dependency in my package.json.

Now, when I'm working in one of my components .vue files, I want to import Semantic so I can create a dropdown;

```js
<template>
  <div id='user-button'>

      <div class="ui pointing dropdown top right" id='user'>
        <div class='text'>User</div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="item">Choice 1</div>
          <div class="item">Choice 2</div>
          <div class="item">Choice 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import jquery from 'jquery'
import 'fomantic-ui-css/semantic'
import 'fomantic-ui-css/components/dropdown'

export default {
  name: 'me-dashboard-button-user',
  mounted: function() {
    jquery('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
  }
}
</script>
```

When running this code in the browser, I get a error in my console;

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default(...)(...).dropdown is not a function"
```

When I run the command `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown()` in my console, the dropdown works instantly.

I'm really new to NodeJS and still getting used to work this way. I normally just use the CDN-file for frameworks like jQuery and Vue, but since it's so easy to create Vue-components in different files, I love to work this way.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this question I was experiencing this same issue with EJS templates and Semantic UI. I used a CDN and experienced same issue. Seems like I will go with your console solution and embed it in the template lol.